# Wing Chun sash color rankings in order

Tags: wing-chun

Hello all I am a red sash in Wing Chun and my Sifu is a red sash.  What is the order that the sash system goes in? I am really confused.

Comment: What school of Wing Chun are you part of? There are different ones and no standard system of color.

Answer (score 7):

This depends on your particular school, because sash color and rank are not standardized across Wing Chun schools. Even in the same branch of Wing Chun, your school may have a different tradition than other schools in the same branch.

Very simply, if your school of Wing Chun has everyone wearing the same color sash, then that means that sash color is not important and does not indicate rank. Or maybe all the students get one color, all the instructors get another color, and maybe the sifu / master instructor gets another color. I've seen variations of that in many schools.

It may even just be random. Students pick their sash color to be anything they want in those cases.

In many Wing Chun schools, rank isn't even a thing. They often don't award rank, except maybe for when someone becomes an instructor or master. Some don't even wear sashes at all.

In some Wing Chun schools, the sash is tied on the right side for students, left side for instructors, or vice-versa. In some, it's left side for males, right side for females, or vice-versa. This is going to vary widely.

So my best answer to you is to just ask your instructor or another student about it. They can clue you in on what the sash means, or whether it's completely non-important.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your Sifu. Like the post above. My school didn't even have sashes. We had 3 different t-shirts. Reason being, shirts are more useful and affordable. Everyone started with a white shirt, then when you learned all 3 forms you would be awarded a blue, once you became an instructor or master you would be awarded the black.

Answer (score 0):

There are no ranks or grades in the original art of Wing Chun. It wasn't even a complete system just 100 years ago. Prior to Yip Man, it had been taught only from one practitioner to another, so grading didn't make much sense.

Most ranking systems derive from Japanese tradition. There is no standard rule set for Wing Chun. Every school or foundation may have their own. Shape and color usually reflect the number of years trained, exams passed or other achievements. There might even be honorary grades.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your system. Your Sifu with establish the curriculum and grading system. They could use tshirts, badges or shashes.

In my previous school red sash means SiHing and blue sash means instructor. Gray sash was reserved for the chief instructor.

IMHO sashes or badges don't matter so much.